# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable (While working on google colaboratory)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-colaboratory

In python I got a "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" during execution.

I had read other posts but I still can't figure out why it is like this.

```
# Python code to find if a number is
# prime or not using divmod()

# Given integer
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
x = n

# Initialising counter to 0
count = 0
while x != 0:
    p, q = divmod(n, x)
    x -= 1
    if q == 0:
        count += 1
if count > 2:
    print(n, 'is Not Prime')
else:
    print(n, 'is Prime')
```

And, please note that it doesn't gives any error by replacing:

`n = int(input("Enter a number"))` to `n = int(input("Enter a number"))`

I have also provided a screenshot regarding my problem

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaR4o.png)

Answer if anybody knows, Appreciation for any suggestions and comments.

Comment: Your code works fine, take a look [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18WVDJf4UBb-5xES4NIeDStirtluxi3XH?usp=sharing)

Comment: in another part of the notebook, someone assigned `int=something` or `from x import *` , which broke your code, so you should add `from builtins import int` to undo whatever he has done.

Comment: @AhmedAEK AEK **Yess** maybe you are right, but, I am not able to resolve it therefore I have shared my [Colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11zn2Y7hgIgIA925L_WnAN3atyoec_5-M?usp=sharing). Please, do me a favor by fixing it.

Comment: yep that's there `int = -94` .... change this variable to another name then restart the interpreter.

Comment: @excitedmicrobe As you said, It made me figure out that after making a new google colab file, all errors were fixed. But, I wanna know why this happened. I have shared [Colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11zn2Y7hgIgIA925L_WnAN3atyoec_5-M?usp=sharing). Please, see why this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
z = input("Enter a number")
n = int(z)
x = n
```

Comment: Thanks For Replying, the issue has already been resolved. Your, suggestions were also great